# gstreamer-1.0 UDP receiver test pipeline

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, mpeg-2

I want to receive an UDP video stream with gstreamer. Well, the final goal is to play it into a QML page, which in turn use gstreamer as backend.

Thus, first I want to test at the low-level.

Opening the stream with VLC reveals:

> MPEG-1/2 Video (mpgv) 
>   720x576 
>   50 fps 
>   Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Because I'm running a custom Linux system I'm not sure if I have all the gstreamer plugins I need.

I have:

```
# gst-inspect-1.0 | grep mpeg2
libav:  avenc_mpeg2video: libav MPEG-2 video encoder
libav:  avdec_mpeg2video: libav MPEG-2 video decoder
omx:  omxmpeg2videodec: OpenMAX MPEG2 Video Decoder

# gst-inspect-1.0 | grep udp
udp:  udpsink: UDP packet sender
udp:  multiudpsink: UDP packet sender
udp:  dynudpsink: UDP packet sender
udp:  udpsrc: UDP packet receiver
```

What is the minimum pipeline I can use to receive this UDP stream?

Comment: I'm able to see incoming raw data with gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=1000 ! fakesink dump=1, but I don't know how to decode and display video

Comment: try to use, gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=8000 ! <Demuxer If needed tsdemux> ! <Decoder> ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink